# How to change capturing audio file format

Tags: c++, audio, format, capture

i'm using embarcadero c++;
how to edit capturing file formats
i need to make mp3 file.

default it makes ~2sec wma file's size ~ 331KB

Comment: The Q is vague and incomplete, clarify and, by the way, what have you tried so far?

Comment: i want to capture an audio file in format "mp3"